# Junit Test Case Issue With Mockito & Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Below is my main class where main logic delete operation is written:

```
public class EmployeeCrudOperation {
    
public void deleteEmployee(String id) {
   StringBuilder deleteQuery = new StringBuilder("DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = ?");
   PreparedStatement preparedStapreparedStatement tement = null;
   Connection = null;

   try{
       //connection = DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
       //it contains JNDI connection code called under static block
       connection = getConnection();
       if(connection == null) {
           logger.logMessage("some text");
           return;
    }
    preparedStatement = connection.PreparedStatement(deleteQuery.toString());
    preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
    int n = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    if(n == 0) {
        logger.logMessage("some message");
    }
    if(preparedStatement != null) {
          preparedStatement.close();
    }
   } catch(SQLException e) {
     logger.logMessage("some message");
   } catch(Exception e) {
     logger.logMessage("some message");
   } finally {
     try {
        if(preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }
     } catch(Exception e) {

     }
     try {
          if(connection != null) {
                 connection.close();
          }
     } catch(Exception e) {}
 }
 }
public Connection getConnection() {
    return DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection(); 
     //it contains JNDI connection code called under static block
}

}
```

JUnit Test case in which I used mockito framework, mock function etc:

```
public class TestEmployeeCrudOperation {

@Mock
Connection connection;

@Mock
PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

@Test
public void testDeleteEmployee() {
EmployeeCrudOperation employeeCrudOperation = new EmployeeCrudOperation();
EmployeeCrudOperation spyEmployeeCrudOperation = Mockito.spy(employeeCrudOperation);

try {
    
    when(spyEmployeeCrudOperation.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
    when(connection.preparedStatement(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(preparedStatement);
    when(preparedStatement.executeUpdate()).thenReturn(1);
    
    spyEmployeeCrudOperation.deleteEmplotee("1");
    
    verify(spyEmployeeCrudOperation, times(1)).deleteEmplotee("1");

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```

Is this test case correct? Also  code coverage is showing very low. How can I increase the code coverage?
Also while debugging code is not going inside the actual class. please guide.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First fix your class, use `JdbcTemplate` instead of the contraption you have now. Also you aren't testing anything only if you are calling the method (which you do as you can see that).

Comment: I can't modify the actual code because that is written by other team member. my responsibility is to write test case. is there a way to do so?

Comment: Convince them, this is the wrong way to write JDBC code with Spring. You would need to mock the JDBC stuff and verify that, I doubt you can intercept the internal method call to get the connection.

Comment: I don't agree with this approach.  Mocking a database?  What is that proving?  If you're testing a repository, connect to a real database and execute the operations.  Make them transactional so you leave the database in the same state that you found it in.  Mocks aren't helpful or illustrative in this case.

Comment: That JDBC code is awful.  I thought you were using Spring. Why are you not using JdbcTemplate?  I'd scrap that code and start again.

Comment: What is your test testing? Nothing really: `crud.delete(); verify(crud, times(1)).delete();` – what do you want to verify here; that the Java compiler is generating the correct bytecode and the JVM really called the method?

Comment: @knittl : please tell me what changes I should make in the test case.

Comment: 1. Run your test against a real DB (ideally embedded or dockerized) 2. Check that `deleteEmployee` does what it advertises - removes existing employees. How: add employee - check if select query finds them - delete the employee - now same query should not find them. +1 for JdbcTemplate.